# regex/beautifulsoup how to extract the all values of column from html table?

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

From this code:

```
<tr><td>PC1</td><td>zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:ce</td><td>10.0.0.244</td><td>23 hours, 55 minutes, 25 seconds</td></tr>
<tr><td>PC2</td><td>zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:cf</td><td>10.0.0.245</td><td>23 hours, 23 minutes, 27 seconds</td></tr>
```

I'd like to get an array of MAC addresses and another array of ip's

I thought something like that regex for the macs: `<\/td><td>(.*?){17}<\/td>`
but it match the uptime too.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you already know that mac addresses are in the second column, use lxml (faster than beautiful soup) with an xpath query. You don't need regex.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074586/extracting-selected-columns-from-a-table-using-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `html` you have given, you could do the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<tr><td>PC1</td><td>zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:ce</td><td>10.0.0.244</td><td>23 hours, 55 minutes, 25 seconds</td></tr>
<tr><td>PC2</td><td>zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:cf</td><td>10.0.0.245</td><td>23 hours, 23 minutes, 27 seconds</td></tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
mac_ips = []

for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    cols = [td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')]
    mac_ips.append((cols[1], cols[2]))

for mac, ip in mac_ips:
    print '{}  {}'.format(mac, ip)
```

Giving you:

```
zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:ce  10.0.0.244
zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:cf  10.0.0.245
```

i.e `mac_ips` would hold each row as a matching pair:

```
[(u'zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:ce', u'10.0.0.244'), (u'zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:cf', u'10.0.0.245')]
```

---

If you want to separate lists then you could do the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<tr><td>PC1</td><td>zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:ce</td><td>10.0.0.244</td><td>23 hours, 55 minutes, 25 seconds</td></tr>
<tr><td>PC2</td><td>zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:cf</td><td>10.0.0.245</td><td>23 hours, 23 minutes, 27 seconds</td></tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
mac = []
ip = []

for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    cols = [td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')]
    mac.append(cols[1])
    ip.append(cols[2])

print mac
print ip
```

Giving you:

```
[u'zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:ce', u'zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:cf']
[u'10.0.0.244', u'10.0.0.245']
```

Note: If you are parsing more html, then you will probably also need to first find the enclosing `<table>`.

Answer (score -2):

```
try:
    table = soup.find('table')
except AttributeError as e:
    print 'No tables found, exiting'
    return 1

# Get rows
try:
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
except AttributeError as e:
    print 'No table rows found, exiting'
    return 1
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem