# Read scraped data vertically out of table instead horizontally Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i'm writing a web scraper with python and beautifulsoup to get data out of a table from a webpage.
Link to the table is in the code (url01)

I want to know if there is a possibility that the data will be read vertically and not horizontally from the table

Here is my code

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import islice

#URL declaration
url01 = 'https://www.statistik.at/web_de/statistiken/wirtschaft/preise/baukostenindex/030979.html'

#BeautifulSoup4
response = requests.get(url01, timeout=5)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

#deletes all the empty tags
empty_tags = content.find_all(lambda tag: not tag.contents)
[empty_tag.extract() for empty_tag in empty_tags]

#Find all td in class body in div table table-hover
data = content.find_all('td')
#print (data)

numbers = [d.text.encode('utf-8') for d in data]
#print (numbers)

#create string
str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in numbers)
#print (str1)

str_splt = str1.split('b')
#print (str_splt)

#Split list into several sublists
length_to_split = [45, 45, 45, 110, 110, 110, 188, 188, 188, 253, 253, 253, 383, 383, 383]
Input = iter(str_splt)
Output = [list(islice(Input, elem))
          for elem in length_to_split]
print (Output[3])


#Python dictionary
dataDict = {
    '2015 Lohn': None,
    '2015 Sonstiges': None,
    '2015 Insgesamt': None,
    'Insgesamt': None
    }

dataDict['Insgesamt'] = str_splt
#print (dataDict)

#save dictionary in json file
with open('indexData.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(dataDict, f)
```

When I execute the program and want to print out my first sub list, then these are the results. It has the wanted length (45) but it was read horizontally out of the table which makes it useless

```
['', "'108,6'", "'110,8'", "'109,8'", "'122,1'", "'114,3'", "'118,0'", "'140,6'", "'131,9'", "'136,0'", "'162,0'", "'166,3'", "'165,2'", "'261,9'", "'189,8'", "'222,5'", "'108,6'", "'111,4'", "'110,1'", "'122,1'", "'115,0'", "'118,4'", "'140,6'", "'132,6'", "'136,4'", "'162,0'", "'167,2'", "'165,7'", "'261,9'", "'190,8'", "'223,1'", "'105,2'", "'111,9'", "'108,9'", "'118,2'", "'115,5'", "'117,1'", "'136,2'", "'133,2'", "'134,9'", "'157,0'", "'168,0'", "'163,9'", "'253,7'", "'191,7'"]
```

Comment: You can transpose a table using `zip`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting selected columns from a table using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074586/extracting-selected-columns-from-a-table-using-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution, without `pandas`. The function `get_column()` returns column as tuple, indexed from 0:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import islice

#URL declaration
url01 = 'https://www.statistik.at/web_de/statistiken/wirtschaft/preise/baukostenindex/030979.html'

#BeautifulSoup4
response = requests.get(url01, timeout=5)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

rows = []
for tr in content.select('tr')[:-1]: # [:-1] because we don't want the last info row
    data = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td')]
    if data:
        rows.append(data)

def get_column(rows, col_num):
    return [*zip(*rows)][col_num]

print('2015 Lohn:')
print(get_column(rows, 0))

print('2015 Sonstiges:')
print(get_column(rows, 1))

print('2015 Insgesamt:')
print(get_column(rows, 2))
```

Prints:

```
2015 Lohn:
('108,6', '108,6', '105,2', '105,2', '105,2', '105,2', '104,4', '105,2', '105,2', '105,2', '105,2', '105,2', '105,2', '105,2', '105,2', '102,9', '102,9', '102,9', '102,9', '102,6', '102,9', '102,9', '102,9', '102,9', '102,9', '102,9', '102,9', '102,9', '101,9', '101,9', '101,9', '101,9', '101,5', '101,9', '101,9', '101,9', '101,9', '101,9', '101,9', '101,9', '101,9', '100,8', '100,8', '100,8', '100,8', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')
2015 Sonstiges:
('110,8', '111,4', '111,9', '111,0', '111,6', '112,4', '112,6', '113,1', '114,6', '114,8', '114,3', '113,8', '113,0', '113,3', '112,7', '111,4', '110,5', '109,9', '110,0', '106,3', '108,9', '108,9', '108,3', '107,3', '105,7', '105,0', '105,2', '106,1', '106,5', '105,1', '104,3', '104,1', '97,7', '101,6', '99,6', '99,1', '98,5', '98,5', '98,3', '98,9', '98,5', '96,2', '94,1', '93,9', '94,9', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')
2015 Insgesamt:
('109,8', '110,1', '108,9', '108,4', '108,7', '109,1', '108,9', '109,5', '110,4', '110,4', '110,2', '109,9', '109,5', '109,6', '109,3', '107,6', '107,1', '106,8', '106,8', '104,6', '106,2', '106,2', '105,9', '105,4', '104,5', '104,1', '104,2', '104,7', '104,4', '103,6', '103,2', '103,1', '99,4', '101,7', '100,6', '100,4', '100,0', '100,0', '99,9', '100,2', '100,0', '98,2', '97,1', '97,0', '97,6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas` library:

- [pd.read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) - produces a list of dataframes (there could be multiple tables in an HTML source), get the desired one by index.
- [df.to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) - To saved data into csv file.

---

```
import pandas as pd

#read html page table data.
table = pd.read_html("https://www.statistik.at/web_de/statistiken/wirtschaft/preise/baukostenindex/030979.html")
#saved data into csv file
print(table[0].to_csv("indexData.csv"))
```