# I am trying to extract a specific column from a html table using pandas

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd
fiddy_states = pd.read_html('https://www.infoplease.com/us/postal-information/state-abbreviations-and-state-postal-codes')
print(fiddy_states[0][0])
```

I am getting an error which I am not able to understand. Since I am new to this I can't find the solution.
I just want the zip code column from the table in the url.

Comment: So what is the error you get?

Comment: This is part 1 of the error- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MOCHI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
 
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

Comment: File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

Comment: Put the error message in your post to get more pay attention, not in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of Web Scraping tools like beautiful soup or selenium. and the question itself is unclear! Tell me why are you using pandas for HTML page?

If you want to extract a column from a web page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074586/extracting-selected-columns-from-a-table-using-beautifulsoup) is a solution already available.

Comment: I was doing an online course on data analysis. The course uses pandas and I am stuck at this point. In order to follow the course I have to solve this in pandas only. The course instructor was able to extract a specific column using fiddy_states[][] notation. I am getting an error in this situation.

Comment: make sure required directories are installed in your system

Answer (score 0):

The Link you provided has two table - hence two corresponding dataframe.

You can get them by :

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd
fiddy_states = pd.read_html('https://www.infoplease.com/us/postal-information/state-abbreviations-and-state-postal-codes')
# First Table
fiddy_states[0]['Postal Code']
# Second Table
fiddy_states[1]['Postal Code']
```